# Retain check boxes checked whenever i hit back button after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php

While filling forms,Whenever I hit the "back" button, all of my entered information remains in the fields, except for checkboxes.
This is the code i used for checkbox using php(drupal)

```
  $container =array('cartons' => t('Cartons'),
                    'glass_bottle_jars' => t('Glass Bottles and Jars'),
                    'metal' => t('Metal Cans/Lids and/or Foil'),
                    'plastics' => t('Plastic Containers ≤ 5 Gallons'),
                    'not_sure' => t('Not Sure'));   
  $form['types_container'] = array(
     '#type' => 'checkboxes',
     '#title' => $this->t('Containers:'),
     '#size' => 1,
     '#validated' => TRUE,
     '#options' => $container,
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript's **[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)** if you want sticky-form on the client-side. Visit the link and follow the examples provided.